# $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ , $H$ be a proper subgroup of order $m$ such that $(n/m)!<2n$ ; $G$ is not simple

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ , $H$ be a proper subgroup of order $m$ such that $(n/m)!<2n$ ; then how to show that $G$ is not simple ? I have proceeded by Cayley's theorem , $\ker f$ is normal and contained in $H$ ; so it is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ , we need moreover a non-singleton normal subgroup , which I am not able to get . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Hint: Recall $G$ acts transitively on $G/H$.

Comment: Could you fill out your explanation a little. What is $f$?

Comment: @MarkBennet I think $f$ is the homomorphism induced by the action of $G$ an $G/H$?

Comment: @ArpitKansal That may well be the case, but $G$ can act on subsets or subgroups in different ways - e.g. by multiplication or by conjugation. I think it is up to the person asking the question to define the terms used rather than those of us who might answer having to guess. Sometimes thinking these things through to express them in writing helps the person who asked the question to understand better what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $G$ is simple. Consider the action on the coset space $G/H$ by left multiplication. This induces a homomorphism $\rho:$ $G \to S_{\frac{m}{m}}$ with $\ker \rho \triangleleft H$. Since $H$ proper, and $G$ simple, then $\ker \rho=\lbrace 1 \rbrace $. So $\rho $ injective. Lagrange's theorem implies that $n$ divides $(\frac{n}{m})!$ and since $(\frac{n}{m})!<2n$, then we mut have $n=(\frac{n}{m})!$, so $G \cong S_{\frac{n}{m}}$. Now since $G$ is simple and $H$ is proper, we must have $n>2m$ (any subgroup of index 2 is normal!)and so $\frac{n}{m} \geq 3$, but $S_{k}$ for $k \geq 3$ is not simple. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $G$ is simple. So the action $f$ of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ has trivial kernel. That is, $f$ is an injective homomorphism $f:G \to S_{n/m}$ to the symmetric group of degree $n/m$. Hence $|G| = n$ divides $(n/m)!$. But then $(n/m)! < 2n$ implies $n = (n/m)!$, so $f$ must be an isomorphism, and $G \cong S_{n/m}$, which is not simple, contradiction.